# Not giving an 'out' argument

Tags: c#

It is possible to assign default values to normal arguments to a function, such that

```
bool SomeFunction(int arg1 = 3, int arg2 = 4)
```

can be called in any of the following ways.

```
bool val = SomeFunction();
bool val = SomeFunction(6);
bool val = SomeFunction(6,8);
```

Is there a way of doing something similar (other than just creating an unused variable) such that

```
bool SomeOtherFunction(int arg1, out int argOut)
```

can be called in either of the following ways?

```
int outarg;
bool val = SomeOtherFunction(4,outarg);
bool val = SomeOtherFunction(4);
```

Is this at all possible, or if not, what are good workarounds? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good workaround is:

```
bool SomeOtherFunction(int arg1, out int argOut){ ... }

bool SomeOtherFunction(int arg1)
{
    int dummyArgOut;
    return SomeOtherFunction(arg1, dummyArgOut);
}
```

I'd even say its the **best** workaround.

Comment: Can you qualify why you would say it is the best?

Comment: @3Pi: Because it gives you the very same semantics than using default values for normal arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use an overloaded version of the same method that doesn't take a second argument:

```
public bool SomeOtherFunction(int arg1)
{
    int ignore;
    return SomeOtherFunction(arg1, out ignore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, ref and out parameters cannot have default values. Workarounds will depend on what exactly you want to achieve. One way is to wrap it into another method (or overload ) and pass the out variable from that method.

Answer (score -1):

There is no default argument in C#, to do the similar thing, you should implement overload method.
Or you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx), which you must handle the arguments by yourself

Comment: I don't understand the link - how does `params` help with implementing an optional `out` parameter?

Comment: @PaulBellora: I solves only a half of your problem (without out keyword)! The best way to implement overload methods!